# Task Queues, Idempotence, and Objectify Transactions

Tags: google-app-engine, transactions, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

The [documentation for GAE's Task Queue API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/#Java_Tasks_within_transactions) states:

> You can enqueue a task as part of a datastore transaction, such that the task is only enqueued—and guaranteed to be enqueued—if the transaction is committed successfully.

However, the [documentation for datastore transactions](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions) states twice that we should make them idempotent whenever possible, and submitting to a task queue is not idempotent.  The [documentation for objectify](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Transactions) takes this a step further, explaining that `work MUST be idempotent` within its transactions.

So, is there a standard way to handle combining these recommendations/requirements, or should I roll my own technique (perhaps using something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22362192))?

Comment: I'm not sure where you're finding the contradiction here. If you're in a transaction, then the task is added transactionally, so that if the transaction fails, the task is not enqueued.

Comment: @DanielRoseman The reason transactions are recommended/required to be idempotent are for a situation like this: the transaction throws a `DatastoreFailureException`, but then succeeds anyway, so the task is enqueued.  Objectify retries the transaction, and it succeeds again.  Now your task has been enqueued twice, because enqueuing a task is not idempotent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also the concern that a task can execute twice (or more) - the queue provides "at least once" semantics not "exactly once" semantics. This is common.

Some operations are easy to make idempotent (eg, "set birthdate"). Some operations can be difficult to make idempotent (eg, "transfer $5 from account A to account B"). For the difficult ones, usually the trick involves creating a transaction id outside of the start of the transaction sequence and making sure that id follows the whole chain, even through tasks. If anything retries and sees the transaction id has already been completed, you can just return.

Comment: Ohhh - it seems that part of the Task Queue documentation did not stick with me.  Thank you for pointing it out!  So, the answer is that I have to make the tasks themselves idempotent anyway, so enqueuing one twice is no problem!  Thank you much.

Answer (score 1):

If the task was enqueued than anything else in its associated transaction was committed as well. Yes, technically it is possible for a transaction to be committed and still get
an error response (e.g. a timed-out accepting the successful response) though that is not common. In any case your task should be idempotent as well (it could use the data committed
in its own transaction to help with that) as the task could be executed more than once even if you submitted it once. see [Why Google App Engine Tasks can spuriously be executed more than once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151218/why-google-app-engine-tasks-can-spuriously-be-executed-more-than-once).